# Timeout error when connecting to a particular webservice API from corporate network using R

Tags: r, web-services, proxy

I am trying to connect to webservices from corporate network and facing some problems.

I am using the following set of statements

> library(httr)
>
> swapiurl<-"http://swapi.co/api/planets/?search=alderaan"
>
> alderaan <- GET(swapiurl)
>
> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
>
> Couldn't connect to server

I get the above error message.

I then enabled the proxy settings as below

> Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://aproxy.xxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx.net:8083")

and again run the above command and it works

> alderaan <- GET(swapiurl)
>
> alderaan$status_code
>
> [1] 200

However, when I try to connect using the proxy settings to a commercial product the company purchased, we are not able to connect and getting timeout error.

> entraderurl<-"https://ngcsi.contigohosting.com/Entrader_Dev/wcfservices/TradingService.svc"
>
> auth<-GET(entraderurl,authenticate("Username","Password"),timeout(60))
>
> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>   Timeout was reached

When I try the same using another non-corporate network and remove the above proxy settings, I am able to connect to enTrader.

> auth<-GET(entraderurl,authenticate("Username","Password"),timeout(60))
>
> auth$status_code
>
> [1] 200

I am using Windows 7 laptop and R Studio version 1.0.136 and R version 3.3.3.

I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's include this line as well

```
Sys.setenv(https_proxy="http://aproxy.xxxxx.xx.xxxxxxx.net:8083")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Prem, Thanks for the answer. But setting the system environment variable has not worked when I tried to call entrader webservice.

Comment: Did you add `https` entry which I have mentioned above? It should work after this.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much Prem. Sorry I didn't realise https in your response. Thanks again.